# Spring Security, how to handle web-service based authentication

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-webflow, spring-security-oauth2

We are trying to implement authentication and authorization using spring security in our webflow app. There is a service which will authenticate user and return corresponding role of user.

But after this call is it possible to make use of Spring Security configuration in our app, since all the documents related to Spring Security tells that we need to have the username, password as well as roles pre-defined either in xml, properties file or db.

I can store the returned roll in session and completely avoid spring security.But I want to enforce more security to app and keep hackers away.

So is it possible to use Spring Security in this context? Also what about the idea of keeping roles in session?

Please find sample Spring security xml below.Is it possible to assign values to uname/psswrd/role after athentication,run-time. So that all subsequent calls will be handled by spring security then.

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
<security:form-login login-page="/spring/login"
                     login-processing-url="/spring/loginProcess"
                     default-target-url="/spring/main"
                     authentication-failure-url="/spring/login?login_error=1" />
<security:logout logout-url="/spring/logout" logout-success-url="/spring/logout-success" />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-provider>
<security:password-encoder hash="md5" />
<security:user-service>
    <security:user name="keith" password="417c7382b16c395bc25b5da1398cf076"
                   authorities="ROLE_USER,ROLE_SUPERVISOR" />
    <security:user name="erwin" password="12430911a8af075c6f41c6976af22b09"
                   authorities="ROLE_USER,ROLE_SUPERVISOR" />
    <security:user name="jeremy" password="57c6cbff0d421449be820763f03139eb"
                   authorities="ROLE_USER" />
    <security:user name="scott" password="942f2339bf50796de535a384f0d1af3e"
                   authorities="ROLE_USER" />
</security:user-service>
</security:authentication-provider>
```

http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider, will this cover my scenario?

Comment: You wrote: "There is a service which will authenticate user and return corresponding role of user." -- does your application invoke this service and submit the login and password to this service, or how is the user authenticated?

Comment: Yes we first inoke the service for authentication.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Spring-Security. If you can tweek you service, so that it provides the password instead of checking it, the only thing you need to do is implementing your own [`UserDetailsService`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.2.3.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/core/userdetails/UserDetailsService.html).

Just take an example configuration for Spring Security, that use an `JdbcDaoImpl`-`UserDetailsService` or an `InMemoryDaoImpl`-`UserDetailsService`, and then replace them by your `UserDetailsService` that invokes the web-service.

If you are not able to provide the password, then you need to implement/configure your own [`AuthenticationProvider`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/AuthenticationProvider.html). Either you use the [`RemoteAuthenticationProvider`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/rcp/RemoteAuthenticationProvider.html) or implement a subclass of [`AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/authentication/dao/AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.html).

I recommend the `RemoteAuthenticationProvider` way:

```
<http>

    ...
    <security:authentication-provider ref="remoteAuthenticationProvider" />
  </http>


  <bean id="remoteAuthenticationProvider" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.rcp.RemoteAuthenticationProvider">
    <property name="remoteAuthenticationManager" ref="myRemoteAuthenticationManager" />
  </bean>

  <bean id="myRemoteAuthenticationManager" class="MyRemoteAuthenticationManager"/>
```

You only have to implement `MyRemoteAuthenticationManager` that implements `RemoteAuthenticationManager`. The Interface `RemoteAuthenticationManager` has only one method:

```
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> attemptAuthentication(String username,
                                                             String password)
                                                       throws RemoteAuthenticationException;
```

In your implementation this method must invoke your webservice.

Comment: can you please explain little more?

Comment: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-authentication-provider, is this helpful in my case?

Comment: I added some more details.